# ggplot2 multiple axis titles

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, shiny

I have almost completed my code, but I have one more minor issue. I need to change the x and y axes depending on the input from the dropdown menu. For example, if x = Sales, any y = R&D, then the x axis should be "Sales (millions $)" and the y axis should be "R&D (millions $)," and so on. But the y axis can be Sales and the x axis can be R&D as well, which is confusing me. Here is my code so far:

UI:

```
ui = dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Apple Financials"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    fileInput("file1", label = "Upload SAS Data:", accept = ".sas7bdat"),
    selectInput("x", label = "X-Axis Variable", choices = c("Sales" = "SALEQ", "Cash" = "CHEQ", "Assets" = "ATQ", "Profits" = "OIADPQ", "R&D" = "XRDQ", "SG&A" = "XSGAQ")),
    selectInput("y", label = "Y-Axis Variable", choices = c("Sales" = "SALEQ", "Cash" = "CHEQ", "Assets" = "ATQ", "Profits" = "OIADPQ", "R&D" = "XRDQ", "SG&A" = "XSGAQ"), selected = "XRDQ"),
    selectInput("scale", label = "Choose the Scale:", choices = c("Levels" = "identity", "Log 10" = "log10")),
    radioButtons("model", label = "Choose the Model:", choices = c("Linear Model" = "lm", "LOESS" = "loess", "Robust Linear" = "rlm", "None"), selected = "loess"),
    checkboxInput("ribbon", label = "Standard Error Ribbon", value = TRUE),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.model == 'loess'",
      sliderInput("span", label = "Span for LOESS", min = 0, max = 1, value = .75)
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    box(width = NULL, height = 415, plotOutput("plots"))
  )
)
```

Server:

```
  server = function(input, output) {

 output$plots = renderPlot({
   data = input$file1
   if(is.null(data))
     return(NULL)
  df = read_sas(data$datapath)

 ggplot(df, aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y)) +
   geom_point(size = 2) +
   geom_smooth(method = input$model, span = input$span, se =                           
    input$ribbon) +
   scale_x_continuous(trans = input$scale) +
   scale_y_continuous(trans = input$scale) +
   theme_minimal() +
   validate(
     need(input$x != input$y,
          paste("X and Y variables have to be different"))
     )
   })
  }


  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lab_choices = c("Sales" = "SALEQ", 
                "Cash" = "CHEQ", 
                "Assets" = "ATQ", 
                "Profits" = "OIADPQ", 
                "R&D" = "XRDQ", 
                "SG&A" = "XSGAQ")

ui = dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Apple Financials"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    fileInput("file1", label = "Upload SAS Data:", accept = ".sas7bdat"),
    selectInput("x", label = "X-Axis Variable", choices = lab_choices),
    selectInput("y", label = "Y-Axis Variable", choices = lab_choices, selected = "XRDQ"),
    selectInput("scale", label = "Choose the Scale:", choices = c("Levels" = "identity", "Log 10" = "log10")),
    radioButtons("model", label = "Choose the Model:", choices = c("Linear Model" = "lm", "LOESS" = "loess", "Robust Linear" = "rlm", "None"), selected = "loess"),
    checkboxInput("ribbon", label = "Standard Error Ribbon", value = TRUE),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.model == 'loess'",
      sliderInput("span", label = "Span for LOESS", min = 0, max = 1, value = .75)
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    box(width = NULL, height = 415, plotOutput("plots"))
  )
)

server = function(input, output) {

 output$plots = renderPlot({
   data = input$file1
   if(is.null(data))
     return(NULL)
  df = read_sas(data$datapath)

 ggplot(df, aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y)) +
   geom_point(size = 2) +
   geom_smooth(method = input$model, span = input$span, se =                           
    input$ribbon) +
   labs(x = paste(names(lab_choices)[lab_choices == input$x], "(millions $)"), 
        y = paste(names(lab_choices)[lab_choices == input$y], "(millions $)")) +
   scale_x_continuous(trans = input$scale) +
   scale_y_continuous(trans = input$scale) +
   theme_minimal() +
   validate(
     need(input$x != input$y,
          paste("X and Y variables have to be different"))
     )
   })
}
```

Since `input$x` and `input$y` are both strings, you can just add

```
labs(x = paste(input$x, "(millions $)"), 
     y = paste(input$y, "(millions $)"))
```

**Edit:**

OP made a point about wanting to use the names as they appear to the user as axis labels instead of the variable names. Since both value and names are needed, one can create a global variable of label choices, supply to shinyUI as is and supply the `names` to shinyServer that matches `input$x` and `input$y`. Note the changes to `choice =` in `selectInput` and `labs` in `ggplot`

Comment: Wow thanks! So when I do that it prints out, for example, "SALEQ (millions $)," but I want it to say "Sales" instead of the actual variable name

Comment: @Tarzan See my edits. Since your question is not reproducible, which to be fair is hard for a shinyApp, I cannot test it. So please let me know if there are any further issues.